# Remove COMPLETELY a connection/ storyboard

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, xcode-storyboard

I made a TableViewController and did a connection of the TableView to its class interface.
Then I wanted to change the TableView name, did the connection another time to be sure but when launching app I have NSUnknownKeyException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ClassementGroupe2 0x7597f60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ClassementGroupe2TableView.'
```

It's searching for the old name! My question is how to remove a connection from any pre connected outlet? `'ClassementGroupe2TableView'` is the old name and it's no longer present in any part of my code. But it is surely present in some code since I have that error.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the storyboard, select the view, open the Connections Inspector (the right-most icon in the right sidebar), and press the little x right next to the connection.

Comment: OMG, how I did not see that ? Thank you :). Accepted ;)